# I using @Query and Pageable has error: Variables are only allowed when ordering by an expression referencing a column name

Tags: java, spring, pageable

I tried to query:

```js
 @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM BookingOffice WHERE tripId in (select Trip.tripId from Trip Where Trip.desfination like ?#{#desfination})   ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}",
   countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BookingOffice WHERE tripId in (select Trip.tripId from Trip Where Trip.desfination like ?#{#desfination})",
   nativeQuery = true)
 public Page<BookingOffice> findAllByTrip(String desfination, Pageable pageable);
```

My PageRequest:

```js
Sort sort = new Sort(Direction.DESC, "officeId");
PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(page, 7, sort);
```

Hibernate Query on runtime

**> Hibernate:

> ```
> SELECT
>     * 
> FROM
>     BookingOffice 
> WHERE
>     tripId in (
>         select
>             Trip.tripId 
>         from
>             Trip 
>         Where
>             Trip.desfination like ?
>     )   
> ORDER BY
>     ?,
>     officeId desc offset 0 rows fetch next ? rows only**
> ```

ERROR:
May 17, 2020 12:41:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/CarPark] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
***com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The SELECT item identified by the ORDER BY number 1 contains a variable as part of the expression identifying a column position. Variables are only allowed when ordering by an expression referencing a column name.***
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1608)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:578)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:508)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7240)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2869)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:243)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:218)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2171)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1934)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1896)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:936)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2693)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2676)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2510)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2505)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2262)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1069)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1529)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ....

[image: **My database**]

Please help me! Thanks

Comment: You can add your image inline, please follow instructions here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344853/3519504

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using Pageable object in order by clause of your select query. It expects a column name for ordering the results.

Comment: Thank for your answer but can you review my PageRequest. 
Sort sort = new Sort(Direction.DESC, "officeId");
PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(page, 7, sort);, it not work, Thanks!

Comment: Pass officeId as a parameter to your query function directly instead of passing it in PageRequest.

PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(page, 7);

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM BookingOffice WHERE tripId in (select Trip.tripId from Trip Where Trip.desfination like ?#{#desfination})   ORDER BY ?#{#sortColumn} DESC",
   countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BookingOffice WHERE tripId in (select Trip.tripId from Trip Where Trip.desfination like ?#{#desfination})",
   nativeQuery = true)
 public Page<BookingOffice> findAllByTrip(String desfination, String sortColumn, Pageable pageable);

Answer (score 0):

Please try like below, I have done same kind of implementation in my project and it's working fine.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM BookingOffice WHERE tripId in (select Trip.tripId from Trip Where Trip.desfination like %?1%}))",
            nativeQuery = true)
public Page<BookingOffice> findAllByTrip(String desfination, Pageable pageable);
```